# Open bookmarks in chrome onClick

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-studio

I have made an app where the user can access bookmarks in chrome using an onClick event. However when I click my button I get a runtime saying

`PID: 12500                                                              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`

`Caused by: java.lang.reflect`

Not sure what the issue is here. I have also tried

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
```

My code is as fallows

```
  public void onClickbtnSavedArticles(View view) {
        Uri uri =  Uri.parse("chrome://bookmarks/"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lstAddBudget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#555454"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="33dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/savearticle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addBudget"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.58"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Saved Articles"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/savedArticles"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/nextarrow"
            android:onClick="onClickbtnSavedArticles"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sounds like you specify a method that doesn't exist in your `Activity` in your buttons `android:onClick` attribute.

Comment: @BadCash I added my xml and as you can see my `android:onClick="onClickbtnSavedArticles"` does exist